# Navigate to ViewController from @IBDesignable UIView didSelectRowAt UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a @IBDesignable View file and implemented tableview in it. Data is coming and tableView in working but only I am facing issue at the time of select cell which has to open to other ViewController. Because its a @IBDesignable view file, not a viewController.swift

How to navigate to viewController from @IBDesignable UIView tableview cell select with passing values?

Error: `has no member 'navigationController'` if I use self.

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let actionType = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].actionType

    switch actionType {
    case 5:
        print(actionType ?? 0)
        let urlLink = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].actionUrl
        let titleText = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].textValue
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
        vc.url = urlLink ?? ""
        vc.titleText = titleText ?? ""
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    default:
        print(actionType ?? 0)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello, if you use a Xib file for your table view you should use a Controller to instantiate it, isn't it ?

Comment: @EtienneJézéquel its a IBDesignable class UIView.

Comment: Yes, but it's embedded in a ViewController ?

Comment: @EtienneJézéquel  Yes. In ViewController I have tabbarController type button at bottom and on one of the button click it act like a popup view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UITableView` is a `UIView` so it's not a `UIViewController` and has not `UINavigationController`.

You should create a `delegate` in your `UITableView` that will be implemented by your `UIViewController`.

Something like that :

```
protocol MyTableViewDelegate: class {
    func didSelectRow(url: String, titleText: String)
}
```

Add a delegate variable in your table view like :

```
weak var delegate: MyTableViewDelegate?
```

and call your delegate like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let actionType = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].actionType

    switch actionType {
    case 5:
        print(actionType ?? 0)
        let urlLink = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].actionUrl
        let titleText = AppData?.items?[indexPath.row].textValue
        self.delegate.didSelectRow(url: url, titleText: titleText)
    default:
        print(actionType ?? 0)
    }
}
```

In your view controller :

you should add your table view custom class into your ViewController,

then add delegate : `yourTableView.delegate = self`

implement delegate :

```
extension MyViewController: MyTableViewDelegate {
    func didSelectRow(url: String, titleText: String) {

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
        vc.url = urlLink
        vc.titleText = titleText
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. I implemented all only getting one error at add delegate `yourTableView.delegate = self`   I used it in viewController  `viewDidLoad`  Am I doing right?

Comment: Yes you are doing right, how do you add your table view to your controller ? you should have something like this : `@IBOutlet weak var historyTableView: YourTableView!` ?

Comment: Done it. Thank you. I am making one mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent view controller using this extension:

```
extension UIView {
  var viewController: UIViewController? {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
      if let responder = responder as? UIViewController {
        return responder
      }
      responder = responder?.next
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

You can use it like this in your code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
vc.url = urlLink ?? ""
vc.titleText = titleText ?? ""
self.viewcontroller?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

> Note: Although you can get the parent controller of UIView, it is not
>   recommended as the UIView should not be aware of the controller. I
>   suggest using Delegates.